# Converting numbers 1,2,3,4 to 001,002,003,004

Tags: arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser

How can i convert a field 1,2,3,4... to 001,002,003,004...010...?

For example

```
1 change to 001
2 change to 002 
3 change to 003
```

...

Is there any formula in field calculator?

[image]

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Use Field Calculator with Python parser and the [zfill](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.zfill) method:

> Pad a numeric string s on the left with zero digits until the given
>   width is reached

Pre-logic script code:

```
def pad(code):
    return str(code).zfill(3)
```

And call with:

```
pad( !Code!)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another solution in Field Calculator with Python parser could be achieved with the use of zero padding and width flags

```
def oldblock(code):
    return "%03d" % code
```